# MATLAB GUI) Initial Tab selection

Tags: matlab, user-interface, editbox

I am making a simple GUI that reads some parameters in `EditBox` and do something.

I have a lot of `EditBoxs` and it is convenient to move by <kbd>Tab</kbd> Button between boxes.

I want the text in the next box to be initially selected by <kbd>Tab</kbd> Button so that I don't need to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and remove the text before typing new strings.

I couldn't find any information from web, and searched in the Property Inspector of `Editbox` but no luck.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll likely have to leverage the underlying Java. See Yair's post in [this MATLAB Central thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/285437).